# Geting ORA-01017 after copying oracle home directory to different linux server

Tags: linux, oracle-12c, sqlplus

-- Oracle V 12c

I have two different servers. I have copied the entire oracle directory from one server to another, and now I am using made relevant changes in .bash_profile.

when executing `sqlplus`, getting the following error:

`ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password`